# Set data only if there is a Date value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have this query:

```
         SELECT 
                mc.equipment as equipment
              , CONVERT (DATE, mc.CreatedOn)  as Data
              ,  sum(mc.quantity) as Production
              , tc.PlannedProduction as ProductionPlanned
              , ABS((sum(mc.quantity) - tc.PlannedProduction)) as ProductionVSPlanned
        FROM 
            AT_MACHINE_COUNTER mc INNER JOIN
            TC_PlannedProduction tc ON mc.equipment = tc.Workcenter
        WHERE 
          mc.CounterType = 1 
          and mc.CreatedOn between @DATA_START and  @DATA_END 
          and tc.PlannedDate between @DATA_START and  @DATA_END 
                      and mc.equipment = @MACHINE 
          and mc.CreatedOn IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY CONVERT (DATE, mc.CreatedOn), mc.equipment, tc.PlannedProduction
```

It works and this is the result:

```
       --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       | Equipment      | Data          |Production     | PlannedProduction | Production vs Planned|
       --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       | COMBINER001    |2014-11-24     |1097.8920000000|   16000           |  14902,108           |
       | COMBINER001    |2014-11-25     |2065.3200000000|   16000           |   13934,68           |
       | COMBINER001    |2014-11-26     |752.1720000000 |   16000           |   15247,828          |
       | COMBINER001    |2014-11-27     |1176.9720000000|   16000           |   14823,028          |
       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But this result is not correct because in TC_PlannedProduction there isn't value for 25,26,27-11-2014
I expected a null value for column PlannedProduction for the record where the column Data is (25,26,27/11/2014)

Can we help me?
reguards

Comment: The results of your query would *strongly* imply that the data does exist.  Perhaps you can set up a SQL Fiddle with a relevant sample of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JOIN condition you are currently using will match anything by Equipment and Workcenter; there's no consideration of what date goes where.

If you're trying, as I assume, to match the planned production of a specific day with the actual production of a specific day, you could try changing your `JOIN` condition to be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and adding a date field from TC_PlannedProduction (I'm assuming PlannedDate, but since I don't know your data I can't confirm that).

```
     SELECT 
            mc.equipment as equipment
          , CONVERT (DATE, mc.CreatedOn)  as Data
          ,  sum(mc.quantity) as Production
          , tc.PlannedProduction as ProductionPlanned
          , ABS((sum(mc.quantity) - tc.PlannedProduction)) as ProductionVSPlanned
    FROM 
        AT_MACHINE_COUNTER mc LEFT JOIN
        TC_PlannedProduction tc ON 
            mc.equipment = tc.Workcenter AND
            CONVERT (DATE, mc.CreatedOn) = CONVERT (DATE, TC.PlannedDate) -- don't know if you need the second CONVERT() function
    WHERE 
      mc.CounterType = 1 
      and mc.CreatedOn between @DATA_START and  @DATA_END 
      and tc.PlannedDate between @DATA_START and  @DATA_END 
                  and mc.equipment = @MACHINE 
      and mc.CreatedOn IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY CONVERT (DATE, mc.CreatedOn), mc.equipment, tc.PlannedProduction
```